# VBA - Using Range("A1").Formula = But the formula is over 3 lines so I am using _ at the end, but the IF statement on the next lines are giving errors

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, line-breaks

Range("A1").Formula = "=IFERROR(If('AUX Table'!A3=""Yes"", IF('Legend'!C1=""Yes"", _
If('Aux colour table'!V1=""Yellow"", etc etc

Comment: Either put it all on one line or research how to concatenate strings over multiple lines. Other than for readability, there is no reason to spread over multiple lines anyway.

Comment: @ACCtionMan there is a limit in the VBA editor

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the first line with a `"` then start the new line with the same.

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=IFERROR(If('AUX Table'!A3=""Yes"", IF('Legend'!C1=""Yes"","_ 
"If('Aux colour table'!V1=""Yellow"""
```